# Strange array signature

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

Recently saw the following chunk of code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    0[&a] = a+a;//What is this??? 
}
```

Could anybody explain, what this means?

Comment: Where did you see such code?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, in c++ quiz. This code compiles well - a becomes 6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is some ugly code -- but it's perfectly legal (in both C and C++).

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/827263) (with [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/381549/827263) and [my attempt to provide some historical context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18393343/827263). the `[]` indexing operator is commutative, so

```
0[&a] = a+a;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(&a)[0] = a+a;
```

`&a` is the address of the `int` object `a`. The indexing operator takes a pointer operand and an integer operand. Typically the pointer is an array name (or equivalently, in this context, a pointer to the array's first element). But a single object can, for purposes of indexing and pointer arithmetic, be treated as an array with a single element.

The previous declaration is:

```
int a = 3;
```

The assignment treats the `int` object `a` as if it were a single-element array of `int`, and refers to that array's element `0` -- which happens to be the only element that exists.

The previous value of `a` is 3, so `a+a` is obviously 6.

So this:

```
int a = 3;
0[&a] = a+a;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int a = 3;
a = a + a;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int a = 3;
a = 6;
```

which ultimately is equivalent to this:

```
int a = 6;
```

In a typical professional software engineering environment, it's *effectively* equivalent to:

```
int a = 6; /* Please reject this submitted code and consider firing me. */
```

Comment: Of which Stroustrup writes "Such
cleverness has no place in production code." (CPL4 7.4.1)

Comment: @dhavenith: Years ago, when I was first learning C, I wrote `#define EVER ;;` ... `for (EVER) ...`. I thought it was very clever. I *still* think it's very clever -- I just no longer think that's a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

Array subscripting in C is a bit strange.  The standard defines `E1[E2]` as equivalent to `*(E1+E2)`.  Of course, addition is commutative, so this is equivalent to `*(E2+E1)`.  Which makes it equivalent to `E2[E1]`...

With this in mind, your second line becomes:

```
(&a)[0] = a+a;
```

which you'll probably agree is equivalent to:

```
*(&a) = a+a;
```

or

```
a = a+a;
```